# Arrange openair plots in a grid

Tags: r, lattice, openair

I'd like to arrange a series of plot generated through the `openair` package in a grid. Here's an example from the [openair book](https://bookdown.org/david_carslaw/openair/sec-polarPlot.html#conditional-probability-function-cpf-plot)

```
library(openair)
polarPlot(mydata, poll = "so2", stati = "cpf", percentile = c(0, 10))
polarPlot(mydata, poll = "so2", stati = "cpf", percentile = c(10, 20))
polarPlot(mydata, poll = "so2", stati = "cpf", percentile = c(20, 30))
polarPlot(mydata, poll = "so2", stati = "cpf", percentile = c(30, 40))
polarPlot(mydata, poll = "so2", stati = "cpf", percentile = c(40, 50))
polarPlot(mydata, poll = "so2", stati = "cpf", percentile = c(50, 60))
polarPlot(mydata, poll = "so2", stati = "cpf", percentile = c(60, 70))
polarPlot(mydata, poll = "so2", stati = "cpf", percentile = c(70, 80))
polarPlot(mydata, poll = "so2", stati = "cpf", percentile = c(80, 90))
polarPlot(mydata, poll = "so2", stati = "cpf", percentile = c(90, 100))
```

I tried `par(mfrow=c(5, 5))` as well as `gridExtra::grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,...)`. Neither of them work. I noticed that in the boookdown [book code](https://github.com/davidcarslaw/openair-book/blob/master/polar-plots.Rmd) the plots are nicely arranged in a grid.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't understand :-( The first link points to section 8 where the polarplots are displayed: https://bookdown.org/david_carslaw/openair/sec-polarPlot.html#conditional-probability-function-cpf-plot
The second link points to the Rmd of the same section, where on line 149 the full code chunk is shown: https://github.com/davidcarslaw/openair-book/blob/master/polar-plots.Rmd

Comment: At the bottom of the bookdown section 8 points back to [multiple_plots](https://bookdown.org/david_carslaw/openair/sec-openair-package.html#sec:multiple-plots-page) section 2.8 that maybe gets us there. I would have chosen the par(mfrow approach, but appears he goes about it differently.

Comment: Oh wow, I completely missed that. I don't think I would have figured out to use `print()` this way.

Comment: Me neither, though I suppose we should expect it under the 'there's always another way to do it paradigm'. Now I'll read his docs too!

Answer (score 1):

When running `openair::polarPlot`, the console shows this message:

```
this contains:
    a single data frame:
    $data [with no subset structure]
    a single plot object:
    $plot [with no subset structure]
```

If you save the plot as an object, you can call just the plot using $plot:

```
object1 <- polarPlot(mydata, poll = "so2", stati = "cpf", percentile = c(0, 10))
object2 <- polarPlot(mydata, poll = "so2", stati = "cpf", percentile = c(10, 20))

object1$plot
object2$plot
```

You can then arrange and export the plots as you would with any plot objects such as with `ggarrange` and `ggsave` (or whichever functions you prefer).

```
ggarrange(object1$plot, object2$plot) %>%
ggsave('file.png')
```

Ben